# Resolving ambiguity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, overloading, ambiguity

I have a controller with 3 overloads for a create method:

```
public ActionResult Create() {}
public ActionResult Create(string Skill, int ProductId) {}
public ActionResult Create(Skill Skill, Component Comp) {}
```

in one of my views I want to create this thing so I call it like this:

```
<div id="X">
@Html.Action("Create")
</div>
```

but I get the error:

> {"The current request for action 'Create' on controller type
>   'XController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create() on type
>   X.Web.Controllers.XController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Create(System.String, Int32) on type X.Web.Controllers.XController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(X.Web.Models.Skill,
>   X.Web.Models.Component) on type X.Web.Controllers.XController"}

but since the `@html.Action()` is passing no parameters, the first overload should be used.  It doesn't seem ambiguous to me (which only means I don't think like a c# compiler).

can anyone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, overloading methods is not supported in ASP.NET MVC. You have to use difference actions or optional parameters. For example:

```
public ActionResult Create() {}
public ActionResult Create(string Skill, int ProductId) {}
public ActionResult Create(Skill Skill, Component Comp) {}
```

will changes to:

```
// [HttpGet] by default
public ActionResult Create() {}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Skill skill, Component comp, string strSkill, int? productId) {
    if(skill == null && comp == null 
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSkill) && productId.HasValue)
        // do something...
    else if(skill != null && comp != null
        && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSkill) && !productId.HasValue)
        // do something else
    else
        // do the default action
}
```

OR:

```
// [HttpGet] by default
public ActionResult Create() {}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string Skill, int ProductId) {}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAnother(Skill Skill, Component Comp) {}
```

OR:

```
public ActionResult Create() {}
[ActionName("CreateById")]
public ActionResult Create(string Skill, int ProductId) {}
[ActionName("CreateByObj")]
public ActionResult Create(Skill Skill, Component Comp) {}
```

[See also this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536119/mvc3-routing-with-overloaded-query-parameters/7536515#7536515)

Comment: yes, I see... thanks for the careful reply.  you get a point :)

Comment: A shame the linked question was deleted. 7536119/mvc3-routing-with-overloaded-query-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActionName` attribute to specify different action names for all the 3 methods