# MVC Ambiguous Action for Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

I've got an ASP.NET MVC4 website (using vs2012) that allows users to login by clicking the "login" link.  I'm getting the infamous error:

`The current request for action 'Login' on controller type 'AccountController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Login() on type MyProject.Controllers.AccountController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Login(MyProject.Clients) on type MyProject.Controllers.AccountController`

I've checked a bunch of links on here, including:

[Resolving ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831896/resolving-ambiguity)
[Ambiguous action method call, for some reason ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894766/ambiguous-action-method-call-for-some-reason-asp-net-mvc-3)

and a few more outside of SO.  I've made sure I have the methods decorated correctly but still can't find the reason this is happening.

Here's my code for the "Login" link:

```
    <ul class="topnav navRight">
        @if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" id="ViewLogin">LOGIN</a></li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ClientStats")">STATS</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")">LOGOUT</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
```

and my Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : CustomController
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/Logout
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public virtual ActionResult Login(Clients model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Security security = new Security();

        if (WebSecurity.Login(model.Username, model.Password))
        {
            using (MyProjectContext db = new MyProjectContext())
            {
                int userID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.Username);
                Data.User user = db.Users.Find(userID);

                if (user != null)
                    if (user.Active)
                    {
                        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                            return RedirectToAction("Admin", "ClientStats");
                        else
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClientStats");
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password.");

    return View(model);
}
```

}

The `CustomerController` has nothing special in it but here it is anyways:

```
    public class CustomController : Controller
{
    public enum PageNames
    {
        Home,
        Services,
        Testimonials,
        Video,
        Photo,
        FAQ,
        About,
        Contact,
        Events,
        Profile
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]); }
        set { Session["UserId"] = value; }
    }

    public static string GetPageTitle(PageNames pageName)
    {
        string pageTitle = "Welcome to My Website!";

        switch (pageName)
        {
            case PageNames.Services:
                pageTitle = "- Services";
                break;

            case PageNames.Testimonials:
                pageTitle = "- Testimonials";
                break;

            case PageNames.Video:
                pageTitle = "- Videos";
                break;

            case PageNames.Photo:
                pageTitle = "- Photos";
                break;

            case PageNames.FAQ:
                pageTitle = "- Frequently Asked Questions";
                break;

            case PageNames.Contact:
                pageTitle = "- Contact Us";
                break;

            case PageNames.Events:
                pageTitle = "- Calnedar of Events";
                break;

            case PageNames.Profile:
                pageTitle = "- Profile";
                break;
        }

        return pageTitle;
    }

    public static Data.User ClientInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the routing information...I've tried to uncomment the one route (and changed it's name) but I still get the same error:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "id",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**  I've tried the suggestions of commenting out the routing values and adding `[HttpGet]` to the Login method but it still throws the same error.  I do recall this working at one time so I don't know what has changed lately to make it do this all of a sudden.  Could it be something in the Web.Config?

Comment: Could be the two identical routes you have (#1 and #3, since ID is optional).  Remove/comment out first route and leave only the default for now.

Comment: I tried commenting out each of them (one at time) and both times it still gave me the same error.

Comment: What url does `Url.Action("Login", "Account")` generates?

Comment: Also, try to remove the first route (not the `IgnoreRoute`), you should not need it and it may cause your problem.

Comment: try changing order of AllowAnnonymous and HttpPost...

Answer (score 1):

MVC doesn't support method overloading based solely on signature
take [AllowAnonymous] out

add a [HttpGet] to the get actionresult and the problem should be solved

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I've tried this and I get the same error...which is really odd.

Comment: take [AllowAnonymous] out. LogOut() doesnt need authorize either. you'd be better off authorizing whatever you need. I am editing the answer

Comment: Thanks again but still a no-go unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it turned out to be the fact that I had opened System.Web.Http namespace, which also defines [HttpGet]/[HttpPost] attributes. These attributes were therefore being used in preference to those in System.Web.Mvc, the latter being the ones responsible to allowing method overloading in controllers, based on Http verbs. Commenting out

```
 open System.Web.Http
```

resolved the problem, allowing Mvc to choose the correct ([HttGet]) overload.